# QToolButton: click when enter(return) pressed

Tags: button, qt4

I had to change a QPushButton to a QToolButton. I used the setDefault() and setautoDefault() options for the QPushButton to click the button when enter(return) pressed but now I cant find a way to do the same with the QToolButton.

Is there any advice how I can solve this?

Comment: Why did you change QPushButton to QToolButton?

Comment: Because I added some Icons to the Buttons

Comment: and the icons should be above the text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are for some reason forced to use a QToolButton instead of QPushButton, then those methods are no longer available to you. You would need to manually hook up signals from the other widgets to trigger a click on your button.